# Grails Spring Security Testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, spring-security

I use the Grails Spring Security Plugin for my project and now want to unit test my code. I have the following code in my controller:

```
def index() {
    redirect action: 'show', params: [id: springSecurityService.currentUser.id]
}
```

My Test Class has the following code:

```
void testIndex() {      
    controller.index()
    assert "/user/list" == response.redirectedUrl
}
```

This test fails:

```
| Running 8 unit tests... 1 of 8
| Failure:  testIndex(xxx.UserControllerTests)
|  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'currentUser' on null object
    at xxx.UserController.index(UserController.groovy:12)
    at xxx.UserControllerTests.testIndex(UserControllerTests.groovy:19)
```

How can I authenticate a spring security user in a test case? How would you write the unit test?

Answer (score 7):

You have to use functional tests for security. Unit tests use mocking but don't have plugins available, or a real request. Spring Security is implemented with a filter chain, so you need a real running server. If you use mocks, you're just testing the mocking.

Answer (score 4):

For something this simple I wouldn't bother with complicated mocks, a straightforward

```
controller.springSecurityService = [currentUser:[id:1]]
```

would be sufficient.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '{currentUser={id=1}}' with class 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to class 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService' due to: groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException: Cannot set readonly property: currentUser for class: grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService`

Comment: @lmo the mock I've suggested will only work if you use `def springSecurityService` in your controller, it won't work if you have a typed declaration `SpringSecurityService springSecurityService`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your reference to `springSecurityService` is null.  As long as you have a field in your controller named `springSecurityService`, it should be injected.  Are you using it as a local variable only in your index method and did not declare it as a field?

My `UserController` is as follows:

```
class UserController {

    /**
     * Dependency injection for the springSecurityService.
     */
    def springSecurityService

    ....
 }
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments to this answer, you did declare a `springSecurityService` field in your controller.  I took my working application and tried a test that mirrors yours with my controller method:

```
@TestFor(UserController)
class UserControllerTests {

    void testSomething() {
        controller.register()
    }
}
```

I got a NullPointerException as well.  From Burt's answer, (I did not know this), I think the `springSecurityService` instance is null in the contexts of the Unit Test execution.

Comment: In my controller I have:

    class UserController {
 
 def springSecurityService
        ...

Comment: Should I write that down in the ControllerTest?

Comment: @user1726376 No, you shouldn't need it in the ControllerTest.  I was just making sure you had a reference to `springSecurityService` due to the fact that you had the error message "Cannot get property 'currentUser' on null object".